# How to get object type by object itself in c#

Tags: c#, derived-class, base-class

```
DerivedType x = new DerivedType ();// I don't know what
```

I need to create instance of object by object **x**. Somehow like that:

```
BaseType y = Activator.CreateInstance (Type.GetType (x));
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why can't you use generics or the factory pattern?

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance(x.GetType);` how ever Activator.CreateInstance returns object. or `Activator.CreateInstance(x.GetType.BaseType);`

Answer (score 1):

You can get base type:

```
Type baseType = x.GetType().GetTypeInfo().BaseType;
```

But it seems that you do something wrong in general.

Comment: Kirill Bestemyanov, thanks for reply. May be I'm doing something wrong. I need to create instance of derived class dynamically, but I don't know what type will it be.  I need something like that : **BaseClass itemCopy = (itemOfDerivedClass.GetType()) Activator.CreateInstance (itemOfDerivedClass.GetType ());**, but compiler doesn't allow to do such kind of type conversation.

Comment: What the aim that you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to enumerate properties of derived class, handle them and write that object to database with Entity Framework.

Comment: What do you mean as handle? There are possibilities in Entity Framework to handle properties of its object. May be you wrote another question and say more details?